# Eliminating ideal voltage source for node analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-source, ideal

I have a circuit that I would like to convert into a conductance matrix for the node analysis by inspection method. I have, however, run into a problem. I have this 36V ideal voltage source with no resistance on its branch, which means that I cannot convert it into a current source with the Norton/Thenevin equivalent circuit theorem (or can I?).

I have thought of making the third node connected to the voltage source dependent on the first node connected to the voltage source, i.e. `v1 = v1 + 36`. I have tried this method, but I do not get the correct values. Am I messing up? Is there no way to handle ideal voltage sources with the node analysis by inspection method?
[image: http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~tymerski/ece241/Examples_Node_Mesh.pdf]

Answer (score 2):

<s>After some time searching i've found this [link](http://qucs.sourceforge.net/tech/node14.html#SECTION00413000000000000000) where the "Example 3" and the explanation that follows talks about this situation.</s>

Using mesh analysis by inspection would be great too but the current sources need to be transformed to the equivalent, so it would not be a fast analysis.

---

edit:

Thanks for the tip Elliot Alderson.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcNFys.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this case, the matrix of unknowns will be a combination of two ( "***vs***" index is for "voltage source"), as seen on the Modified Nodal Analysis, as seen on [here](http://qucs.sourceforge.net/tech/node14.html#SECTION00413000000000000000).

$$
\textbf{x}=
\begin{bmatrix}
   v_{nodes} \\ i_{vs}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
   v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \\ I_4
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The same thing happens to the the results matrix, where this is obtained as a combination of the known in/out currents on the nodes and the voltage sources (out of node as negative):
$$
\textbf{y}=
\begin{bmatrix}
   i_{nodes} \\ v_{vs}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
   I_{node1} \\ I_{node2} \\ I_{node3} \\ V_4
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
   12+I_4 \\ -18 \\ 24-I_4 \\ 36
\end{bmatrix}
$$

You have then **n** nodes and **m** independent voltage sources. If those **m** independent voltage sources on the circuit are in the same situation as the 36 V source, you need to add **m** lines and columns to the conductance matrix.

If you do the normal inspection and get an (**n** x **n**) matrix, notice that for the elements below the line **n** you will put the voltage equations for each source (the equation \eqref{eq1} is the 4th line on the conductance matrix below). As for the columns after the column number **n**, here we put the factors of each current on the **Ivs** matrix, where the factors can be 0, +1 or -1 (the opposite sign of the one seen on the above **y** matrix). By doing this, the **y** matrix can be shown without **I4**, as seen on equation \eqref{eq2}.

$$v_1-v_3 = V_4 = 36~\textit{V} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

$$
\textbf{G}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{12} & -\frac{1}{12} & 0 & -1 \\
-\frac{1}{12} & \frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{15} & -\frac{1}{15} & 0 \\
0  & -\frac{1}{15}  & \frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{6}  & 1  \\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{2}\label{eq2}
~~\textit{and}~~~~
\textbf{y}=
\begin{bmatrix}
   12 \\ -18 \\ 24 \\ 36
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now solving:
$$
\textbf{G}\times \textbf{x} = \textbf{y}~~\longrightarrow~~
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{12} & -\frac{1}{12} & 0 & -1 \\
-\frac{1}{12} & \frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{15} & -\frac{1}{15} & 0 \\
0  & -\frac{1}{15}  & \frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{6}  & 1  \\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \\ I_4 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
   12 \\ -18 \\ 24 \\ 36
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The solution is shown below and you can check it by simulating the circuit in this answer.
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
v_1 = 57.6\textit{ V} \\
v_2 = -78.4\textit{ V}\\
v_3 = 21.6\textit{ V} = v_{_{6\Omega}}\\
I_4 = 13.7\overline{3}\textit{ A}
\end{array} 
\right.
$$

1. If you want further information and formalization: [here](http://qucs.sourceforge.net/tech/node14.html#SECTION00413000000000000000)
2. As for some examples, the same link on the strikethrough text: [here](https://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/mna/MNA2.html)

Comment: You nailed it! The only answer to actually give what the OP wanted...a conductance matrix. +1

Answer (score 0):

I know the exercise is with nodal analysis but using Thévenin is fast and can be done by inspection:

1. turn off all sources (current sources are open-circuited while the 36-V source is replaced by a short circuit). What resistance do you "see" form the 6-\$\Omega\$ resistance connections? This is \$R_{th}=4\;\Omega\$.
2. use Superposition by alternatively turning off all sources and keep one alive. Compute the voltage when the 6-\$\Omega\$ resistance is temporarily removed from the circuit. Then sum all voltages to get \$V_{th}=36 V\$.
3. Now bias the 6-\$\Omega\$ resistance from the 36-V dc source affected by 6-\$\Omega\$ resistance and, applying a simple resistive divider, you have 21.6 V. the below SPICE shows the steps:

[image]

You obtained this result just by inspection, no equations.

**Edit**: the below Mathcad sheet shows the numerical results:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here you have a different approach.

[image]

Notice that we can write that \$V_1 = 36V + V_3\$, therefore, we can write the nodal equation this way:

For node \$V_3\$

$$-24A+\frac{V_3}{6\Omega}+\frac{V_3 - V_2 }{15\Omega}-12A+\frac{36V+V_3}{4\Omega}+\frac{(36V+V_3) - V_2}{12\Omega}=0$$

And for node \$V_2\$

$$18A+\frac{V_2 - V_3}{15\Omega}+\frac{V_2 - (36-V_3)}{12\Omega}=0$$

And the solution is:

\$V_3 = \frac{108}{5} [V] = 21.6V\$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-24%2Bx%2F6%2B%28x+-y%29%2F15-12%2B%2836%2Bx%29%2F4%2B%28%2836%2Bx%29-y%29%2F12%3D0%3B+18%2B%28y+-+x%29%2F15%2B%28y+-+%2836%2Bx%29%29%2F12%3D0